# Custom font not loading on first visit

Tags: html, css, wordpress, google-chrome, fonts

I created a new website (http://www.glutenfreekate.com) and used a custom font that I'm including in the style.css. I have worked with custom fonts before and never had any trouble. This time I have the following problem:

When I visit the page for the first time or after emptying the cache the font is not loading. In other words: There is no text. It's not using another font but none at all. It seems to leave room for the words though. It just seems to be invisible. When I click anywhere on the page it gets loaded and on every following visit it will be there.

The problem only seems to exist in the current Chrome.

I tried adding it in the style.css that imports all the other style sheets and at the very top of the style sheet that uses the font. Both didn't help.

I tried renaming the font files and font name but without any success.

Here's the code:

```
@font-face {

font-family: 'aaarghnormal';
  src: url('../katebreuerme/fonts/aaargh.eot');
  src: url('../katebreuerme/fonts/aaargh.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('../katebreuerme/fonts/aaargh.woff') format('woff'),
  url('../katebreuerme/fonts/aaargh.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('../katebreuerme/fonts/aaargh.svg#aaarghnormal') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

body {
  font-family: "aaarghnormal", Helvetica, Century Gothic, Verdana, sans-serif, serif, Courier, monospace;
}
```

Any ideas on how to solve this? I don't think it's good if my readers don't see the font on their first visit...

Thanks!

Comment: please provide your css.

Comment: Everything seems to work fine for me in Chrome... Does this problem also occur in incognite mode?

Comment: bprayudha, I edited above to add the code.

Comment: Yes, also occurs in icognito mode and on different computers.

Comment: @bekate have you been able to fix this? I'm running into the exact same issue (in Google Chrome)

Comment: I had the feeling it was gone after including the style sheet in the header instead of importing it to the other one but still have come across it a few times. So no, not solved. It seems to be Chrome only, yes.

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe nothing but you have :

```
@import url("css/style.css");

@font-face {
    font-family: 'aaarghnormal';
    src: url('../katebreuerme/fonts/aaargh.eot');
    src: url('../katebreuerme/fonts/aaargh.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../katebreuerme/fonts/aaargh.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../katebreuerme/fonts/aaargh.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('../katebreuerme/fonts/aaargh.svg#aaarghnormal') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Is your css/style.css use the font ? 
because maybe the first time the font is not loaded yet and you try to use it on the css/style.css,  am I wrong ?

Try to change that and load the font first and include the css/style.css directly in the html file..
Not sure if that will save your problem but it costs nothing to try

Comment: Hi, already tried this. If I put the @import below the fonts it doesn't load the css at all. I now moved the font part back to the imported css file where it is loaded before it is used but that's not making any difference. Problem still occurring, no matter where I move the font part.